# How to extract data from xml file that is deep down the tag

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRecord xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="Record">
  <AvailableCharts>
    <Accelerometer>true</Accelerometer>
    <Velocity>false</Velocity>
  </AvailableCharts>
  <Trics>
    <Trick>
      <EndOffset>PT2M21.835S</EndOffset>
      <Values>
        <TrickValue>
          <Acceleration>26.505801694441629</Acceleration>
          <Rotation>0.023379150593228679</Rotation>
        </TrickValue>
      </Values>
    </Trick>
  </Trics>
  <Values>
    <SensorValue>
      <accelx>-3.593643144</accelx>
      <accely>7.316485176</accely>
    </SensorValue>
    <SensorValue>
      <accelx>0.31103436</accelx>
      <accely>7.70408184</accely>
    </SensorValue>
  </Values>
</ArrayOfRecord>
```

I am only interested in 'accelx' and 'accely' value in this data and need to create a csv out of it.

Update: The code given below breaks when I change the second row with the following. Nothing is displayed because of this;

```
<ArrayOfRecord xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="Record" xmlns="http://schemas">
```

The following code works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse(r"C:\Users\data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

val_of_interest = root.findall("./Values/SensorValue")

for sensor_val in val_of_interest:
    print sensor_val.find('accelx').text
    print sensor_val.find('accely').text
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What XML library are you using?

Comment: @added the code I was trying

Comment: Have you researched how to use XPath?

Comment: @cricket_007, I am looking at it but not getting proper example

Comment: Try `//Values/SensorValue` then loop over those, and get your data

Comment: @cricket_007, how do you call it? Which statement?

Comment: `root.findall` - have you read the documentation on that method? Does it accept XPath?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @cricket_007, please see my edit. The code doesn't work by merely changing the text

Comment: Oh, the schema... right. I'm too lazy to find the duplicate post for that right now :) You are welcome to answer your own question below